# External graphical device for littler or Rscript

Tags: r, graphics, rscript

I really like littler is really great for scripting using R. But i don't how to use external graphics device a la gnuplot (for example using Octave). 
I'm able to produce the desired graph but i have to use Sys.sleep and i don't want to do so, because i want to close it my self in an interactive way or better continue the script without closing the device.

So far this is what my code looks like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env r -t


suppressMessages(require(Cairo))

CairoX11()
plot(rnorm(1000), pch = 19)
Sys.sleep(50)

# some code without closing the graphics window
```

My question is : Do you know a way to achieve that ?

Any hint, document, link or code will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides John's suggestion, you could be explicit and invoke one of the GUI packages to bring up a new 'frame' (or 'window') that then shows the plot.   That will remain on-screen until the user (or an external event) terminates that window.

The [tcltk](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tcltk) package can be used along with the [tkrplot](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tkrplot) package; this is the most portable.  [RGtk2](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RGtk2) is more modern but harder to install / use on Windows as Gtk2 is not exactly native there.  There is more---search for R GUIs here and on other places on the intertubes.

Comment: First of all i would like to thank's you (and Jeffrey Horner) for littler it's really useful and  also easier to use than Rscript (i even do some system admin in my kubuntu with R now !!). You're right about external frame, so far I tried tkrplot, the new r qt interface (qtbase and qtpaint) and even gnuplot (through TeachingDemos) and also I finally find a way to keep my R graphics without using Sys.sleep (I use locator instead and right click to continue the script). I'll try to find a more elegant solution to problem. Thank's again

Comment: Pleasure to be of help.  If you have a succinct little demo involving maybe just tcltk and tkrplot, I'd be happy to add that to the package (and of course give you full credit etc).  What you asked here is a relevant problem, and we should ship with a sample solution.

Comment: Great idea, I'll be very happy to send you  a piece of reproductible code or post it here when I'll finish this work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do that, since these are purposely *non*-interactive ways of running R. I would just run your script in an interactive R session with `par(ask=T)`. That way it'll pause for the user between figures, like the demos in the R documentation.

Comment: thank's for your suggestion..but for my purpose i can't use an interactive R session...